# Badge Idea - Badge for featured question on the Stack Exchange homepage

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, badge-request, hot-questions

Yesterday I've had my English question featured on the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/), peaking at about 36 arbitrary hotness points.
Today I'm left with nothing but measly warm memories.
How about a badge for such questions? (I thought of something like `15-minutes`)

Comment: that was quick! Good luck with getting a decent answer. (I won't comment - not enough knowledge on this topic.)

Comment: Was I asking a question!? Maybe the post isn't clear... Ok, I'm placing [feature-request] back.

Comment: well, there was this, "How about a badge for such questions?" but I was just referring to the general Q&A style - perhaps I should have said, "response".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds nice, but first off:

- it should only be given once, because else it could inflate your badges
- it would probably be better to reward hotness points (though this is partially done by rep already)
- I would only reward it to questions with very high hotness points, so that it's actually hard to achieve

Sadly, this would make them sort of a duplicate of:

- Nice Question - Question score of 10 or more
- Popular Question - Asked a question with 1,000 views

probably coupled with a Nice Answer

So while the idea is quite nice, I think this would only be viable when the new Stack Exchange homepage evolves a bit further

Comment: I thought about that point - a *hot question* is already successful, will naturally get attention and more votes, so it may not *need* that award (my question did get more votes).  If there will be user profiles on the Stack Exchange site the badge can go there, if that helps.